# Using auth0 to simultaneously connect to a legacy server and a new server

Tags: single-page-application, auth0, multiserver

I have a web SPA that currently connects to a Rails backend, authentication handled via auth0.  We have a new server that has some endpoints that the SPA needs to connect to.  What is an elegant way of authenticating against both servers considering I have auth0 implemented in the SPA and the legacy server already?  Is there some way to pass the authenticated token back to the new server from the legacy server?  Or do I just authenticate against both servers when logging in as a user on the SPA?  The user db sits in a separate db, shared by both servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the credentials are stored in your database, then use an Auth0 Custom DB Connection to authenticate against Auth0 from your SPA. Auth0 has quickstart samples for all the popular SPA frameworks / libraries (angular 1.x, 2+, React.js etc). You authenticate against Auth0 (not the legacy or new server). As a result, you receive a (JWT) ID Token and a (JWT) Access Token. It is the Access Token you send from your SPA to each of of your Servers for the purpose of making Authorized requests. Your Server (legacy and new) should be secured to verify the JWT Access Token as valid and optionally check the `scope` attributes match the request endpoint. That's all that is required. The Auth0 documentation covers all this, and there are samples too that demonstrate how to set this up.